# Can you flash a SM-G900P ROM on a SM-G860P?

Tags: rom-flashing

I am an owner of a Galaxy S5 Sport (SM-G860P) and there's very limited support for ROMs out there. I have heard a couple of people saying you can flash a Sprint Galaxy S5 (SM-G900P) ROM on there as long as you flash the Sport kernel on there or something like that. I've also checked the specs and the two phones are nearly identical if that does matter. I don't want to wipe out my phone and then flash something that doesn't work.

Comment: Wanna provide a reference for flashing 900P on a 860P?!